# how to add different arrays to one index in php

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array with key values from 0 to 11 i want to change their index and add them to    separate array

My array is:

```
Array
(
[0] => MongoId Object
(
[$id] => 543d1619c863c7ec077b23c6
)

[1] => my host group
[2] => Redmine : CPU load     CPU utilization     

[3] => MongoId Object
(
[$id] => 543d6f41c863c7bb077b23c6
)

[4] => new group
[5] => Redmine : CPU load     CPU utilization     
beanstakChefClient : CPU load     CPU utilization     

[6] => MongoId Object
    (
        [$id] => 543e091ec863c788477b23c6
    )

[7] => my all my groups
[8] => Redmine : CPU load     CPU utilization     
beanstakChefClient : CPU load     CPU utilization     
Redmine : CPU load     CPU utilization     

[9] => MongoId Object
(
[$id] => 543e0aecc863c7704d7b23c6
)

[10] => my all host groups
[11] => Redmine : CPU load     CPU utilization     
beanstakChefClient : CPU load     CPU utilization     
Redmine : CPU load     CPU utilization     
Redmine : Disk IO SUMMARY     Interface 2  

)
```

but i want my array to be like this.

```
Array
(
[0] =>array(
[0] => MongoId Object
(
[$id] => 543d1619c863c7ec077b23c6
)

[1] => my host group
[2] => Redmine : CPU load     CPU utilization     
)
[1] =>array(
[0] => MongoId Object
(
[$id] => 543d6f41c863c7bb077b23c6
)

[1] => new group
[2] => Redmine : CPU load     CPU utilization     
beanstakChefClient : CPU load     CPU utilization 
)    
[2] =>array(
[0] => MongoId Object
(
[$id] => 543e091ec863c788477b23c6
)

[1] => my all my groups
[2] => Redmine : CPU load     CPU utilization     
beanstakChefClient : CPU load     CPU utilization     
Redmine : CPU load     CPU utilization     
)
[3] =>array(
[0] => MongoId Object
(
[$id] => 543e0aecc863c7704d7b23c6
)

[1] => my all host groups
[2] => Redmine : CPU load     CPU utilization     
beanstakChefClient : CPU load     CPU utilization     
Redmine : CPU load     CPU utilization     
Redmine : Disk IO SUMMARY     Interface 2  
)
)
```

i tried it using foreach loop but not getting can anyone help on this...?

Comment: Where is your PHP code?

Comment: here it is...$count = max(count($newarray1), count($newarray2), count($newarray3));
 $new = array();
 for($i=0; $i < $count; $i++) {
    if (isset($newarray1[$i])) $new[] = $newarray1[$i];
    if (isset($newarray2[$i])) $new[] = $newarray2[$i];
    if (isset($newarray3[$i])) $new[] = $newarray3[$i];
 }


          echo '<pre>';
         print_r($new);exit();

Comment: Edit your question please. And learn formatting your question by reading the FAQ

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question properly you are only trying to extract values from one array and want to add them to a second array with a different key.

You can simply to this in php:

```
$array1 = array(
  0 => array(
    "id" => 1234
    ),
  1 => array(
    "id" => 4321
  ),
);

// new array
$array2 = array();
$array2[20] = $array1[1];
$array2[46] = $array1[0];
```

`$array2` would output the following:

```
Array
(
    [20] => Array
        (
            [id] => 4321
        )

    [46] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1234
        )

)
```